# bi directional binding with variable instead of using emitter?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I was thinking that I needed to leverage the Output annotation in the Child component in my AngularTS component in order to have a parent property changed, but i was thinking that i could just do:  `[(item)]="myItem"` and it would bind correctly.

I was looking at Output and EventEmitters, but that was creating new Variables which were being monitored only to execute functions such as:

```
@Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

and then you would reference it as:

```
(clicked)="myFunc(id)"
```

Given my use case, I dont think Output is needed because I am not executing functions defined in the parent etc, just wanting to update the property, *myItem* in this case.

Is this the correct thought process as to how to bind and whether or not i should be using the Output annotation?

I am adding some sample Code.

Component 1 HTML:

```
<sub-component [(selection)]="selection"></sub-component>
```

Component 1 TS:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() selection: string = "";
    @Output() selectionChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

Sub Component HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

Sub Component TS:

```
export class SubComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() selection: string;
    @Output() selectionChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    doStuff(): void {
      this.selection = "test";
      this.selectionChange.emit(this.selection);
    }
}
```

The issue is that MyComponent has a selection property, but it is never assigned in it, it is actually just passing it up to a level higher, so since it isnt being set in code, I cant say: `selectionChange.emit(this.selection);`.  Given some of the answers, how do i resolve this concept?  Will it pass up automatically, or do i have to create some sort of StreamListener to monitor for variable changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for two way binding you should follow this pattern , pay attention event name should be your input name + `Change`, then two way binding works, in you component when you change the value of `myInput` emit change event.

```
@Input() myInput : type;
@Output() myInputChange: EventEmitter<type> = new EventEmitter<type>();
```

usage

```
<my-component [(myInput)]="input"></my-component>
```

The banana in the box syntax is just a syntactic sugar for something like below

```
<my-component [myInput]="input" (myInputChange)="input=$event"></my-component>
```

Just pay attention this is for `Components` not `Services`

[angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?  Similarly, do I need to create a function then to emit the value, or when myInputChanges, will it auto emit?

Comment: so for two way binding, you should emit the event in your child component whenever the value is changed, then your parent component biding variable will be updated, does it make sense?

Comment: Right, but if the value is changed by a subcomponent, will it auto percolate it up?

Comment: "pay attention event name should be your input name + Change, then two way binding works" - where is it documented? Makes no sense

Comment: The thing I was curious about is that if i am percolating a select html component selection up, i was just assigning the value correctly. I have a variable reference, but I dont have a event reference.  I can, but i figured this could be clean without it.

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius please take a look at https://medium.com/@preethi.s/angular-custom-two-way-data-binding-3e618309d6c7, I try to find reference in angular.io as well

Comment: @Fallenreaper babana-box `[()]` style is nothing except combining `[myVar]` and `(myVarChange)` together to be come [(myVar)]

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius see this as well https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

Comment: Ok, nice. Never knew about this, but also never needed and probably will not need (because if its limitations) :)

Answer (score 0):

Two way data binding like `([clicked])` only works inside the component. As your requirement is to communicate between the parent and child components, you need something which will let the parent or child know that something is changed in other one.

Also, two way data binding works mostly to communicate from view to model (clearly as per angular 1.x.x) and its not meant for communicating from parent to child component and that different from angular 1.x.x and angular +2.x.x

In your case, you can use the `EventEmitor` by `@Output` or a `RxJs` `Subject`.

Hope it answers your questions

Comment: It narrows it a bit.  I am used to doing AngularDart, so im a bit fuzzy on language specifics to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding

A good aproach is to use a property set method to emit change event:

```
private _selection: any;
get selection(): any {
    return this._selection;
}
@Input()
set selection(value: any) {
    if(this._selection === value) {
        return;
    }
    this._selection = value;
    this.selectionChange.emit(this._selection);
}
@Output()
selectionChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

It's mandatory to name `@Output` filed by adding `propertyNameChange` to `@Input` name.
Yo can use it in parent-child-subchild to exchange data.
**parent component**

```
<mycomponent [(selection)]="fieldInParentComponent"></mycomponent>
```

**mycomponent**

```
<subchildcomponent [(childField)]="selection"></subchildcomponent>
```

Note: subchildcomponent aloso have to implement two way binding like in mecomponent.

I'v created an example as looks it is a common question:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2-way-binding?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I see this is the case in Dart, and was doing this approach with AngularDart.  Since there are some parallels with the 2 languages for the Angular use case, this might be the way it is accomplished.  I am not sure if this is the best course of action due to the increased overhead... but it puts me closer to an answer I recognize.

Comment: In my case the event emited in setter, so when subcomponent changes its property it also chain notification to almost top parent component. But if you have several nested components (like nodes in tree view) you can pass for all of them the same context object wich gives this nested componets access to common data.

Comment: Is this *the* way to do it, as the standard for Angular TS Components, or is just 1 of a few approaches.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Looks like commonly (and stackoverflow community always advices it) is to use some kind of service to exchange data between components. But if this data is used only between components wich are nested only in one big component (like I said it may be a tree view or calendar with dates) its better to pass single context object (single for that view).

Comment: @Fallenreaper look at example I'v attached to the answer